# Recovering data from a system corrupted by and interrupted upgrade

Tags: upgrade, data-recovery

My laptop running Ubuntu 14.10 was being upgraded to the latest version when the process froze half way due to the PC being put to sleep.

Now when I start it up I log in and it reverts back to the login page after briefly showing a distorted image.

I tried using a boot USB to access my data, and I can see that it is still intact but the files are unreadable due to a permissions issue.

I have all my university assignments on the PC and it's imperative that I find a solution ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to read the files. You need to copy them over to another piece of storage.

**Easiest method**

Boot from a live DVD and mount the disk where your documents are on. You can mount this disk from the desktop by clicking on the hard disk icon it correspond. See the hard disk icons at the bottom, when you hover over them they will show the destination.

[image]

Open the one you need and select all the files with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and copy them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Now insert an USB into another USB port and copy your files over to this new disk with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. This is to create a backup of your files and to make sure any other action to restore your system can be taken regardless of your personal files.

After this is done confirm the USB has all your files, safely unplug the USB and re-install your system. You can re-install without using a format and you can install with a "preserve personal files". Both will have you keep your documents or just plain format and install.

After this is done plug the USB back into your system and copy the files over to your system and you are good to go.